# "The package linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-56-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it." Error pops up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, operating-system, ubuntu-20.04

Whenever i try to install or update a new package "The package linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-56-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it." error pops up. How can I get rid of this? (Note: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)

Comment: Out-of-date packages get removed from the repository after a while. The current generic kernel version for Ubuntu 20.04 is 5.4.0-61-generic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try upgrading all your packages including your kernel :

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

launchpadlibrarian.net/508370158/linux-modules-5.4.0-56-generic_5.4.0-56.62_amd64.deb

download and install by dpkg -i [file name]

after this, do what you need (update/upgrade/install... )